Android Material3 Slider change color of the last tick mark?
Slider(
    value = bankloanamounttopay,
    onValueChange = { newvalue -> bankloanamounttopay = newvalue },
    valueRange = 0f..maxbankloanpayoffamount(),
    steps = numbankslidersteps(),
    colors = SliderDefaults.colors().copy(
        thumbColor = moneyred(),
        activeTrackColor = moneyred(),

        activeTickColor = Color.Transparent,
        inactiveTickColor = Color.Transparent,
    )
)

I know I can change the color of the internal tick marks, but the final tick mark seems to use the same color as the activeTrackColor. Is there any way to control the color of the last tick mark separately from the activeTrackColor?


You can override the track argument and use the default SliderDefaults.Track, but override drawStopIndicator and drawTick arguments:
val colors = SliderDefaults.colors().copy(
  thumbColor = moneyred(),
  activeTrackColor = moneyred(),
)
Slider(
    value = bankloanamounttopay,
    onValueChange = { newvalue -> bankloanamounttopay = newvalue },
    valueRange = 0f..maxbankloanpayoffamount(),
    steps = numbankslidersteps(),
    colors = colors,
    track = { state ->
      SliderDefaults.Track(
        sliderState = state,
        colors = colors,
        drawStopIndicator = null,
        drawTick = { _, _ -> },
      )
    }
)

